# How to use %d as a decimal integer with %f in the same line?

Tags: c, floating-point, printf

I want to design a function to print the first X(where X is an integer) digits after the decimal(from 0 to X) for a floating point number Y. For eg.
`print_num(12.123456,4)`
should give:

```
   12.0000000
   12.1000000 
   12.1200000
   12.1230000
   12.1234000
```

Here is a program that I tried to write:

```
#include<stdio.h>
void printplaces(float N,int X)
{
    for(int i =0;i<=X;i++)
    {
        printf("%.%df\n",N,i);
    }
}
void main()
{
    printplaces(23.23423342,5);
}
```

But it just prints the output as it is:

```
%df
%df
%df
%df
%df
%df
```

I want to know how I can use %d as an integer with %f on the same line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `*` in place of the precision.  Then you can pass it an an `int` argument:

```
printf("%.*f\n", i, N);
```

This doesn't print any trailing zeros, but you can add that as follows:

```
for (i=0;i<X;i++) {
    printf("%#.*f", i, N);
    if (i<X) printf("%0*d", X-i, 0);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: @plain-rice Glad I could help.  Feel free to [accept this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if you found it useful.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thanks.  Updated.